# how to move the table row data (HTML) from one php page to another

Tags: javascript, html

```
 // searching the country to select(js file)
function search_country(){
  d3.csv("data/totalpopulation.csv", function(data) {
  var v=f1.search.value; 
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      if(data[i].Name==v){
        document.getElementById('tablediv').style.visibility="visible";
        // retrun value
        document.getElementById('poptable').innerHTML+="<tr id='"+data[i].Name+"' class='ComparisonTable'  onclick='current_country(this.id)' style='cursor:pointer'><td>" + data[i].Name + "</td><td>" + (data[i].p1961/1000000).toFixed(2) + "</td><td>" + (data[i].p2016/1000000).toFixed(2) + "</td></tr>";
    }
  }
});
}

// Comparing the Selected Countries
function compare(){
window.location.href='country.php';
}
```

Here, I am selecting the countries from search bar and putting in CompareTable. 
Furthur, On clicking a compare button i should move to next php file (country.php) and carry the same table data to compare them.

```
 document.getElementById('poptable').innerHTML+="<tr id='"+data[i].Name+"' class='ComparisonTable'  onclick='current_country(this.id)' style='cursor:pointer'><td>" + data[i].Name + "</td><td>" + (data[i].p1961/1000000).toFixed(2) + "</td><td>" + (data[i].p2016/1000000).toFixed(2) + "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Just a notice , if you want to display the items only you might do that , otherwise its always better to get a fresh copy of your data by your server side page instead of sending them as an **editable** GET parameter .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an arrya to store the complete tr values

```
var data_arr[];   
function search_country(){
d3.csv("data/totalpopulation.csv", function(data) {
var v=f1.search.value; 
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
  if(data[i].Name==v){
    document.getElementById('tablediv').style.visibility="visible";
    // push value to an object.
    data_arr.push(document.getElementById('poptable').innerHTML+="<tr id='"+data[i].Name+"' class='ComparisonTable'  onclick='current_country(this.id)' style='cursor:pointer'><td>" + data[i].Name + "</td><td>" + (data[i].p1961/1000000).toFixed(2) + "</td><td>" + (data[i].p2016/1000000).toFixed(2) + "</td></tr>");
   }
  }
});
}

// Comparing the Selected Countries
function compare(){
data_arr_json = JSON.stringify(data_arr);
window.location.href='country.php?data='+data_arr_json;
}
```

When you want to get the data of array in `country.php`:

`$data_from_url = json_decode($_GET['data']);`

Comment: Thanks for solution, I got it

Comment: Accepting as answer would be helpful.